# Kitchenette build inquiry

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

Do you think I could add a kitchenette somewhere on the first floor? What would the best spot be? I am trying to imagine where the best spot would be for this or if it's a lost cause. Where/how could I connect the sink to the water pipes?

I imagine removing the stairs on the first floor and adding a spiral staircase instead or something in the garage up to the second floor. That seems quite expensive though.

I'd like a kitchenette with a full-size fridge, a small washer, and a sink. And a few cabinets or floating shelves.

I am attaching the floor plan. A lot of potential tenants want their own kitchen.

[image: floorplan]

Comment: questions asking  for opinions are not allowed here  ... this site is not a brainstorming forum

Comment: *A lot of potential tenants want their own kitchen* Much more than that. You may be *required* to provide that. Local rules for renting out part of a house can get complicated and vary a **lot** by jurisdiction. While plenty of people do rent out "unofficial" apartments, it may be worth your while to check out what "official" rules are in your area before you sink a lot of money into this project.

Comment: A spiral staircase may make it difficult getting furniture up to the upper floors, which show no outside doors in the given plans.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is for the use of a sub-tenant in Bedroom 4? I would put it in the garage, adjacent to the bathroom. Make the garage a 1 1/2-bay. There are smaller cars that would fit. Or appeal to the carless, lots of bikes and storage could go in there. You would have to dig up the floor a bit to find the existing drains to tie into. And perhaps into the wall separating from the bath to find the water supplies.